# C# error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms

On Visual Studio C# Express when I run the script below, I get the following error message on the line saying:

> if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true):
>    Error    1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' and 'bool'

How could I solve this? Code below:

```
public override GH_ObjectResponse RespondToMouseDoubleClick(GH_Canvas sender, GH_CanvasMouseEvent e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new  System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;

    ofd.Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string[] filePath = ofd.FileNames;
        string[] safeFilePath = ofd.SafeFileNames;
    }
    return base.RespondToMouseDoubleClick(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: if (ofdShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you've been reading the [WPF `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190792.aspx) where the method result is `Nullable<bool>`. If, however, you're using [Windows Forms `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c.aspx), that returns [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) - which you clearly can't compare with `bool`.

Have a look at `DialogResult` and see what you *actually* want to do. Note that the documentation claims:

> Return: DialogResult.OK if the user clicks OK in the dialog box; otherwise, DialogResult.Cancel.

... so those should be the only cases you need to consider.

Answer (score 10):

Replace it with:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

`ShowDialog` method returns [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) enumeration, which has following members:

- None
- OK
- Cancel
- Abort
- Retry
- Ignore
- Yes
- No

Answer (score 1):

Compare with on of the values defined for `DialogResult` like DialogResult.OK not boolean.

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

}
```

Possible values of DialogResults are given below. compare with the one you require.

```
DialogResult.None
DialogResult.OK
DialogResult.Cancel
DialogResult.Abort
DialogResult.Retry
DialogResult.Ignore
DialogResult.Yes
DialogResult.No
```