# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get a window to return value when the user clicks the OK button on that form.

I'm trying to used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233526/1115382) as a guide, but I keep getting the error from my title:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult'
```

This is my code:

```
using (var form = new MyNewForm())
{
    if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //line with error
    {
        string val = form.ReturnValue1;        
        string dateString = form.ReturnValue2;
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I **have** read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615481/c-sharp-error-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-system-windo) thread, that is why I have changed the `if` to `form.ShowDialog()`, but the error still appears.

Comment: Are you in WPF or win forms? The signature of ShowDialog differs between the two.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET pretty sure hes in WPF if it is returning a bool?

Comment: If you read both of those, you should notice that they are dealing with winforms and not WPF.

Comment: I'm just a beginner at C#, but can't you just cast the operand on the right side to the desired type?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I am using WPF

Comment: @Kapol If you want your program to crash at runtime instead of failing to compile, sure.  If you want it to actually work, then no.

Comment: @Servy Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The code you are using as a guide is Winforms, not WPF. The two are very different.

Comment: @Kapol You're suppressing the error message without actually fixing the problem.  Why would you expect it to work in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (var form = new MyNewForm())
{
 if (form.ShowDialog() ?? false /*== DialogResult.OK*/) //line with error
 {
    string val = form.ReturnValue1;        
    string dateString = form.ReturnValue2;
    //do stuff
 }
}
```

use the null coalescing operator ??